# "Foolproof"-ish Linux for total antigeeks

Tags: distro-recommendation

I have some friends which do write a lot. For television, movies, articles for magazines and newspapers or novels. Mostly they are very young and not technical savvy. They ask me for help when their Win/Osx brake and I then always try to persuade them to switch to linux.

Well I did now persuade some to install elementary and some Ubuntu but to my disappointment those installs behave even worse than Windows (disapearing files, login loops, the comp does not wake up). I can not control what they are doing on their laptops (duh) so I want to ask:

**What is in Your experience the most "foolproof" Linux distribution right now?**

Comment: http://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/quotes/a/alberteins100015.html

Comment: "Only two things are infinite, the universe and human stupidity, and I'm not sure about the former."

Comment: I don't see any reason for the downvotes. Close votes would be at place, after all this is asking about other distros. But given a good answer, I think neither downvote nor close vote are necessary.

Comment: This is "Ask Ubuntu." The only reasonable recommendation you're going to get here, is Ubuntu. The answers are also obviously going to be based solely on opinion, and there is no objective right/wrong answer, so the question will be closed for that reason.

Comment: @dobey not if I can make my answer so brilliant even Oli does not dare close it >:-D

Comment: I guess some useres, even when they use Ubuntu today, have some experience with other distros. And no one said people settle with the foolproof=ish distro when they experienced. So i would dare to say that Ubuntu users - the experienced ones - may know about othe distros too. I mean this is not a totalitarian site "Vee vill taak onlee abaawt uboontoo! Jaaa!" Or is it? </for noneuropeans: it was irony>

Answer (score 10):

Linux is not meant to be fool-proof. Heck no operating is meant to be fool-proof. **The main fool on any system is the admin; if he is not worth it problems will happen!**

Linux systems in general are identical so there is no "best" or "more foolproof", just a matter of what flavor someone likes most. We have a core kernel called Linux, we have a desktop that is Unity, Gnome, KDE, LXDE, XFCE, Mate. Sometimes this desktop is incorporated into a different download (like we have Kubuntu for KDE) or the operating system has 1 default where you can install another desktop alongside the current one or in place of the current one. And that is not limited to Ubuntu; this basically also applies to Fedora, SUSE, Debian. But the main thing is: for a lot of software we pull in the same software albeit it will be packaged differently between Debian based system and Fedora and SUSE. And even that difference is going to disappear in due time.

Besides that: Ubuntu (Linux in general) is not even a geek operating system though the system is expected to be maintained by a user with knowledge, aka. an administrator, and 1 (the admin) or more people that are normal users.

Yes, it helps if the admin can code software. Yes, it helps if the admin is a computer enthusiast (which does not *per se* mean a geek). It can be a geek, but by no means does it *need* to be a geek.

Main tasks of the admin:

- install software with Ubuntu Software Center;
- update software with the updater;
- fixing bugs users encounter.

Only the last one requires expertise. But this expertise is in using google: you need to be able to copy paste the problem into a google search box and be able to find a question on Ask Ubuntu with an answer that fits the problem. That does not require a user to be a geek. The fix might mean editing text files but even that can be solved by using the instructions provided by the answer containing the fix. It helps if the admin can assess whether the answer posted is a fix to the problem or not. But that is probably just a lack of experience if he can not.

An operating system will, without regard to what it does, execute commands you issue. And in this you are worse off with both Linux and Unix compared to Windows.

We have a command line we use a LOT and for any and everything. It is a tool and like any tool it will do what you tell it to do so 1 "space" added next to a "*" to a "rm" command *will* ruin your system beyond repair.

- disappearing files

Prove it with a use-case otherwise it is meaningless. Ubuntu/Linux (any operating system, even Windows) does NOT willingly delete files. And our filesystem `ext4` has been proven to be stable and reliable. If this is the case it should be reported as a -critical bug-.

- login loops

This generally happens when someone uses the admin account to mess with user accounts and unknowingly changes the permissions of files. General tip: check the `.xsession-errors` file in the home of that user. It will include pointers on what the problem is.

- the comp does not wake up

Can happen but this highly depends on your hardware. Some hardware just refused to play nice and the only solution is to NOT use suspend and/or hibernate. Please search this site for solutions others posted since there will be plenty of them.
Nevertheless: this is a 1st-time usage issue. You check if suspend/hibernate works after 1st install, if it does not you can attempt to fix it, if not possible you disable it. That a user sees this problem happen is the admin to blame, he should have solved this before handing the system over.

> I can not control what they are doing on their laptops

Want to take a wager on that? I can guarantee you that my parents, who use an Ubuntu machine, will not be able to mess that system up besides the own user area (aka /home/$USER) and any user can delete the directories in /home/$USER/. Is that foolish? Yes. Should you prevent it? No.